# How to find dayofweek from date stored in string?

Tags: c#, datetime, datagridview

I have DataGridView where i am showing all details of upcoming movies

[image]

Now from this i have to give discount to movies that are in weekend. i am getting date from datagridview

```
string date = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["Date"].Value.ToString();
```

Now i have to convert this date to dayofweek so i can compare day to dayof week by

```
date == (DayOfWeek.Saturday || DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

I tried to find dayofweek by

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(date);
Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("ddd"));
```

This code is giving me this error

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.DateTime.DateTime(long)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: What is the value of `date` exactly?

Comment: value of date is the date i am selecting from datagridview i.e 3/2/2016
I want to find what dayofweek was it on 3/2/2016?

Comment: Your error message is _really_ weird by the way. `DateTime` structure does not _even_ have a method called `DateTime` which takes `long` as a parameter. I _strongly_ suspect this error comes from somewhere else which you didn't show us, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it's `string`, you can parse it to `DateTime` and check it's [`DayOfWeek` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek) like;

```
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and

```
if(dateValue.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday || dateValue.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
```

I honestly don't understand why you use [`ddd` specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dddSpecifier) since it represents the abbreviated name and since it uses your `CurrentCulture` settings, it may *not* even generate theirs English names.

After your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35745624/how-to-find-dayofweek-from-date-stored-in-string/35745807?noredirect=1#comment59165716_35745807), looks like your string has time part also, you just change the format part like;

```
var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: var dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
this is giving me error of "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime" as the date i am getting from datagridview is like 3/2/2016 12:00:00 AM , even though date showing in datagridview is 3/2/2016 without time. does the string date has to have only date without time?

Comment: @NavazBaig If so, you just change your format to `M/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`. Updated my answer. Take a look.

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = "3/2/2016";
var dayOfWeek = DateTime.Parse(date).DayOfWeek;
```

Comment: I do not recommend this way because your code _might_ parse this string as 3th February or it may not parse it _at all_.

Comment: It will be better use `ParseExact` or (or `TryParseExact` if the format can be change) and a _specific_ culture settings.